# Rails add attribute to active record result

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a model `Menu`

in my index action I want to return Menu.all but I want to add to that a new attribute/value for each menu by calling menu.parent_id

I was trying something like: 
`@menus = Menu.all.map {|m| m.parent_id}`

but this ONLY gives me the parent_id, I need the menu object and the parent id.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to add an attribute. The *ActiveRecord* model `Menu` contains the `parent_id` attribute, when you loop through them you can call the attribute as normal.

In your controller:

```
@menus = Menu.all
```

Then in your view:

```
<% @menus.each do |menu| %>
  <% # do stuff %>
  <%= menu.parent_id # output parent id %>
  <% # do more stuff %>
<% end %>
```

Or if you'll output JSON:

```
json.array!(@menus) do |menu|
  json.extract! menu, :id, :parent_id, :more_stuff
end
```

Or if you want to output the render directly in the controller without the use of views:

```
render json: @menus
```

Comment: Im using rails api so no views. Hence why i want to do it in the controller and add the result of parent_id to the json I get back from the api

Comment: If you're using Rails as API you still render a view. I edited my answer to also include a jbuilder variant.

Comment: Thank you! This wirked perfectly, I wasnt using jbuilder, but I am now.